# WPF RibbonApplicationMenu Cannot Set Drop Down Height

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

Using the Microsoft Ribbon Control in a WPF application and using the application menu like this:

```
<r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <r:RibbonApplicationMenu
        <r:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem Header="Item 1">
            <r:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem.Items>
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 1" />
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 2" />
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 3" />
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 4" />
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 5" />
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 6" />
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 7" />
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 8" />
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Sub Item 9" />
            </r:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem.Items>
        </r:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>
        <r:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem Header="Item 2" />
    </r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
</r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

This is a much shortened version with all the images,commands, tooltips etc properties removed to keep the code much shorter.

The problem is there are only 2 items but one item has many sub items. These sub items then appear as just 2 items with scroll arrows. This is annoying so I tried using the DropDownHeight property on the application menu but it makes no difference. The height is always the size needed for the two main items.

Isn't the DropDownHeight supposed to set the height regardless?